# Font Size Discrepancy on Flag History

Tags: bug, flag-history

When viewing the flag history page, *question* hyperlinks are appearing a bit larger than *answer* hyperlinks. About `4px` larger I believe.

A quick look at the console shows this CSS rule for question hyperlinks, but nothing setting the font-size and weight on answer-hyperlinks.

```
.question-hyperlink {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```
.answer-hyperlink, .question-hyperlink {
    color: #07c;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}
```

---

Notice the second, third and fifth entries, the font is *smaller*.

[image: flag history font-size issue]

I was able to reproduce this on Chrome and Firefox (didn't test IE).

Comment: This is the same in the 10k Tools. It easily helps to distinguish questions from answers without going to the post or looking at the URL. I don't see this as a bug.

Comment: Well it's unpleasant to see, and there is little or no need to distinguish questions from answers here, so I see it more like a bug